# Have dinner/grab a bite/get dinner

Tags: grammar, phrase-choice

Are there any subtle differences among the meanings of these sentences, and are they all correct? Edit: As I think 'grab a bite' is used for a casual meal or a meal eaten quickly. 'Get dinner' implies if you obtain a dinner prepared by someone, especially when you have dinner in restaurants etc.
Except 'have dinner' phrase, can we use these other phrases too for a normal evening meal at home, and how to understand 'get going for dinner'?

I need to have dinner now.

I get going for dinner.

I gotta go grab a bite.

I'm going to get dinner.

Comment: Welcome! Please edit the question to tell a bit more about "how correct" you care to be. Some of the options use colloquial or casual usages, which are fine if you're in a casual context (talking out loud or writing a chat or text), but would not be appropriate in a more formal context like a business letter or academic paper. Also, check carefully; there are a few small errors in punctuation and capitalization; perhaps you don't mean to focus on those?

Comment: Also, it would be nice if you can mention any specific concerns you have. Requests for proofreading are not [on-topic](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), so it's best if you ask about whether specific words or phrases are right or wrong for specific reasons. And yes, there will be *subtle* differences of tone if not meaning, so it might also be nice to say exactly what kind of meaning or tone you want.

Comment: @AndyBonner Thanks for your consideration and advice. I've already edited the question. Because I used ' I need to have dinner now', and someone replied with these phrases as alternatives to what I said in context of a normal evening meal. So I want to know, are these phrases really interchangeable in this context?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All four are acceptable (with one change, below) and fairly interchangeable. They're all casual ways of saying that you intend to eat.

There's one issue: "I get going for dinner" is not idiomatic. It's confusing, because we're already using both "going" and "get" in "I'm going to get dinner." But "get going" is its own phrase, [meaning](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/get-going) "start going," and using it with the simple present tense is awkward. "**I'll** get going for dinner" would be fine.

All the options have essentially the same meaning, but there are *slight*, *subtle* differences of tone:

- *I need to have dinner now.* This is very straightforward and descriptive. It talks about your "need." The tone is a bit blunt and dismissive; it might be appropriate when someone has taken too much of your time and you are not trying to be too courteous.
- *I'll get going for dinner.* This has a pleasant, informal tone. The "get going" would make it especially appropriate if you need to leave the room, perhaps to drive somewhere.
- *I gotta go grab a bite.* This is the most informal. Yes, "grab a bite" can imply that the meal will be short. You *could* use this if you intend to be back in contact after the meal, and are suggesting that it won't take long (though it wouldn't be inappropriate even if you're not coming back).
- *I'm going to get dinner.* This is neutral in tone. "Get dinner" could also be used even if you're preparing it yourself, though if so, you could also use words referencing that, like "fix dinner" or "make dinner" (which imply that you will also eat it).

Comment: Thanks for the perfect answer. I got really confused by these usages